# How to fetch calendar events for a user using Microsoft Graph API with java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I wish to connect a personal Microsoft account(xyz@hotmail.com) to an App and then fetch the calendar events for that account using the App.

I have registered the app in Aure portal and **I am able to fetch the events using Postman**. This is what my postman configuration looks like:

```
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
Call back URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback
AUTH URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID: <Copied from Azure portal>
Client Secret: <Copied from Azure portal>
Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
Client Authentication: "Send as Basic Auth Header"
```

How do I replicate the above using Java? See this tutorail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Check this code from above link:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

EventCollectionPage events = graphClient.me().calendar().events()
    .buildRequest()
    .filter("startsWith(subject,'All')")
    .get();

//Read the SDK documentation for details on how to add the SDK to your project and create an authProvider instance.
```

Here is the link for creating an auth provider:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java

Which provider should I use?

1. Authorization code provider
2. Client credentials provider
3. On-behalf-of provider
4. Device code provider
   etc etc

I am not able to get any of the above to work -- I keep getting too many errors in my java code.

I am able to implement OAuth flow and **have access token and refresh token**. How do I write my Java code to get calendar events?

**EDIT 1**

I have given my code for authentication provider below:

```
public class GraphAuthenticationProvider extends BaseAuthenticationProvider {
    private String accessToken;
    
    public GraphAuthenticationProvider(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
    
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<String> getAuthorizationTokenAsync(URL requestUrl) {
         return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(accessToken);
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
final GraphAuthenticationProvider graphAuthenticationProvider = new GraphAuthenticationProvider(accessCode);
        
        final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(graphAuthenticationProvider).buildClient();
        EventCollectionPage events = graphClient.me().calendar().events().buildRequest().get();
```

This is the error I get:

```
2021-12-15 12:09:10.941 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406Graph service exception Error code: InvalidMsaTicket
2021-12-15 12:09:10.941 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406Error message: ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_REASON_OFFERACTIONS_INVALID'. Message: ''
2021-12-15 12:09:10.942 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406
2021-12-15 12:09:10.943 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events
2021-12-15 12:09:10.944 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.8.0
2021-12-15 12:09:10.945 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406
2021-12-15 12:09:10.947 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406
2021-12-15 12:09:10.949 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406401 : Unauthorized
2021-12-15 12:09:10.950 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406[...]
2021-12-15 12:09:10.951 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406
2021-12-15 12:09:10.951 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 406[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
2021-12-15 12:09:10.951 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] global                                   : Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidMsaTicket
Error message: ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_REASON_OFFERACTIONS_INVALID'. Message: ''

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.8.0


401 : Unauthorized
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
2021-12-15 12:09:10.965 ERROR 14456 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] x.c.controllers.AuthorizationController  : Exception occurred in method: fetchAndStoreMicrosoftRefreshToken

com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidMsaTicket
Error message: ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_REASON_OFFERACTIONS_INVALID'. Message: ''

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.8.0


401 : Unauthorized
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromResponse(GraphServiceException.java:419) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromResponse(GraphServiceException.java:378) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:511) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.processResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:440) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:406) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:223) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseCollectionRequest.send(BaseCollectionRequest.java:102) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseEntityCollectionRequest.get(BaseEntityCollectionRequest.java:78) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.10.jar:na]
    at xyz.calendo.services.EventServices.createEvent(EventServices.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at xyz.calendo.services.UserServices.fetchAndStoreMicrosoftRefreshToken(UserServices.java:160) ~[main/:na]
    at xyz.calendo.services.UserServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa8f5a38.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at xyz.calendo.services.UserServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4a0f13c.fetchAndStoreMicrosoftRefreshToken(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at xyz.calendo.controllers.AuthorizationController.microsoftAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationController.java:85) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? can you please edit question and add the error details

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi-MT - I have added the error details. My main question is how to write the code for authentication provider? I have the following things: 

1) Application ID
2) Application Secret Key
3) Access Code
4) Refresh Token

Comment: Based on the application type you need to use the provider please refer   this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS in java

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi-MT - You are just repeating the information from the question. Which authentication provider should I use? My application runs on a server and will be managing a user's calendar without their intervention. The user will sign in to the application using Oauth and will grant access to my application. Therefore, I will have access to a refresh token and access token. Next time I want to update the user's calendar, there is no need for the user to sign in -- because I already have the refresh token with which I can generate an access token.

Q: How to make use of access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My access token was missing a scope called: "Calendars.ReadWrite". This is how that scope was supposed to be added.

```
AuthorizationCode authorizationCode = new AuthorizationCode(httpServletRequest.getParameter("code"));
        String currentUri = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
        
        IAuthenticationResult result;
        ConfidentialClientApplication app;
        try {
            app = createClientApplication();

            String authCode = authorizationCode.getValue();
            Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
            scopes.add("Calendars.ReadWrite"); //see this line
            
            AuthorizationCodeParameters parameters = AuthorizationCodeParameters.builder(authCode, new URI(currentUri)).scopes(scopes)
                    .build();
            
            Future<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(parameters);
            result = future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }

        if (result == null) {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
        }

        return result;
```

And then, access token was supposed to be requested like this:

```
JWTClaimsSet claims = JWTParser.parse(result.idToken()).getJWTClaimsSet();
String accessToken = result.accessToken();
```